# Retrieving HealthKit data on main thread is causing the app crash for random users - iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, healthkit, dispatch-queue, ios-multithreading

I'm using HealthKit on my app to read user's health data and show them the data in the appropriate place on my app. For some production users(Major impact is on an *iPhone X* user), It's getting crashed while retrieving the health data using HealthKit(**on Main Thread**). But I'm not able to reproduce it.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ashokkumarmw/ce4271db567e4af390c1b290f11b2b77) is my code where I start taking the user permissions and read the health data.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ashokkumarmw/7d741816174cb07a0bb973619840a6c6) is the crash information from fabric.

As per the crash info, it crashed while reading the DOB from HealthKit and I believe that there is no issue in [getting DOB](https://gist.github.com/ashokkumarmw/519f6f033fb13d40909b28d66d7e5e81) and I think the crash is happening because I'm reading health data **on Main Thread** and it might encounter with some multithreading issues. Tried with multiple devices, and I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

1) Any points on why reading the data from `HealthKit` on `Main Thread` is causing the crash?

2) Is the **completion block** I'm running on `Main Thread` **expired/deallocated** and might cause the crash?

Thanks.

Comment: What's on line 307 of MWHealthKit_Read.swift?

Comment: Empty! on the method which contains the code to get the walking&running distance from HealthKit.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bl3gp3eb0sw3x0y/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-15%20at%208.16.18%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: might be issue with accessing deallocated object ‘dispatch_call_block_release+24’ tells that some of the object is deallocated.

Comment: @AshokKumarS Did you find any solution? I am also facing a similar issue

Comment: @PersianBlue No.